# dpkg: error processing package wingide5 (--install):

Tags: package-management, kali-linux

I have been trying to download WingIDE5 onto my kali_linux VM but every time I use the code

```
dpkg -I ~/Downloads/wingide5_5.1.9-1_amd64.deb
```

it just says this

```
Selecting previously unselected package wingide5.
(Reading database ... 323261 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../wingide5_5.1.9-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wingide5 (5.1.9-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wingide5:
 wingide5 depends on libqt4-webkit (>= 4.6.2): however:
  Package libqt4-webkit is not Installed.

dpkg: error processing package wingide5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wingide5
```

So does that mean I just have to download libqt4-webkit, and if so how 
do I download that?
Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Same trouble here... I'm thinking that maybe is the 5.**1**.9 version of the wingIDE, cause I have a book where the example is with the 5.**0**.9 version of the wingIDE, but I don't know if the problem is this and I can't find this version for down and test...

Comment: @guest_world are using the book "Black Hat Python" that's what im using, I don't think it is the version because I have tried version 5.0.9 and it does not work either, same error.  I think the problem might be that libqt4-webkit doesn't work anymore it has been replaced with libqtwebkit4 and so maybe the wingide5 installer cant download it because libqt4-webkit doesn't exist anymore o is uninstallable

Answer (score 0):

> So does that mean I just have to download `libqt4-webkit`

Yes

> and if so how do I download that?

The same way how you downloaded the previous package. Or rather using

```
apt-get install libqt4-webkit
```

which ensures that you have the latest available package and solves for you all the dependencies.

Comment: I did that but then it says that it is up to date and then when I try to install wingide again it gives me the same errors. Thanks for the help though